# Layering (CALayer equivalent in iOS) in GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm working on a graph view and I don't want to redraw the graph plane every time the `onDrawFrame` is called

I'm using GLSurfaceView for this graph; and is there any **iOS CALayers** equivalent in Android were I can just redraw a layer without running again its logic?